# Python Replace() function using an interval between two words

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to improve this program:

```
def not_bad(s):
  s = s.replace("not that bad", "good")
  s = s.replace("not so bad", "good")
  return s
```

*yea, for who knows it come from Google python devs.

In this case, I want that everything between "not * bad" be replaced for good, so doing this works but... if instead of that/so were another words?

I know to answer with the find() but I was wondering if there's a way to do using `replace()`.

Comment: Use `re.sub()` instead. `str.replace()` does fixed replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
#the regular express .*? means match any characters,
#util it comes up with string "bad"
print re.sub('not (.*?) bad', 'good', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
import re
def not_bad (s):
    return re.sub('not (\w+) bad', 'good', s)
```

Comment: Fits perfect! Thank you!
Got one question so, the (\w+) works for only one word, how to use this for n words?